# Python if/elif syntax error... WHY

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm absolutely pulling my hair out over this. The if/elif statement in this function throws a syntax error on the elif line. To me there are no obvious syntax problems.

```
"elif n == cs_index:"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried switching it to a bear "else:" just to see if that would stupidly word and it didn't. I'm sure there's something I don't see.

```
def higherhighlight(cs_index):
    text.tag_remove("the hello","1.0", END)
    idex = "1.0"
    for n in range(cs_index):
        if n < cs_index:
            idex = text.search("Hello", idex, nocase=1, stopindex=END)
            lastidex = idex+"+"+str(len("hello"))+"c"
            idex = lastidex
        elif n == cs_index:
            idex = text.search("Hello", idex, nocase=1, stopindex=END)
            print idex
            lastidex = idex+"+"+str(len("hello"))+"c"
            print lastidex
            text.tag_remove("hellos", idex, lastidex)
            text.tag_add("the hello", idex, lastidex)
    text.tag_config("the hello", background="dark green")
```

Comment: Have you checked that your code is indented properly?

Comment: No syntax errors after pasting the code into my IDE. Must be your indentation.

Comment: Did you mix tabs and spaces perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing tabs and spaces in your code; taking the source of your initial post and pasting it into Sublime Text, then selecting all lines I see this:

[image: source code with spaces and tabs]

The grey lines are tabs, the dots are spaces. I have tabs set to expand to every 4th column, you probably have the same setting.

Python, which expands tabs to every *8th* column, sees this:

[image: same source with tabs set to 8 spaces]

Note how the `elif` indentation **matches the preceding lines**, because the tab character following those 4 spaces is expanded to the *first* 8th column, not a second. This is the cause of the exception you see.

Don't mix tabs and spaces. Preferably, stick to spaces for indentation *only*; it is what the [Python styleguide recommends](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces):

> Spaces are the preferred indentation method.
>
> Tabs should be used solely to remain consistent with code that is already indented with tabs.

Configure your editor to use spaces **only**. You can still use the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key, but your editor will use spaces to indent lines when you do.

Answer (score 1):

After pasting my code into my Spyder IDE and running it, I exhibit no errors (apart from the parentheses missing in the `print` statements - you should really upgrade to Python 3.5.2!)

Try re-indenting that line by resetting the indentation and adding three tabs. I get similar errors when I copy and paste code that uses spaces for indentation.